# Webmin won't listen to any port

Tags: webmin

I have installed Webmin to my Oracle Linux via tar.gz file. 
There is no service webmin. I have to start that 
service manually by typing `/etc/webmin/start` 
1. Why should I have to start it manually?
Why there is no webmin service?

2. When I start service manually, it writes:

> Failed to bind to port 10000:Address already in use

I tried to change port to 20000 in configuration, 
I tried to disable firewall and iptables, 
still problem exists. What can I do to solve? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open the port you ultimately select?
`1. lsof -i :445 
2. netstat -an | grep 445` Replace 445 with your port. (Or similar commands) Show you if it is open.

Comment: my port is not busy